# jqgrid: using setselection as if the user clicked on the row?

Tags: jqgrid

I have a grid (master/detail) with keys bound.  I'd like to have the first row in the master grid automatically selected when the page starts.

I used setSelection in the GridComplete event and can get the row selected.  However, the up/down arrows (and the detail grid) do not function until the user actually clicks on a row with the mouse.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to get a row selected programatically so that the grid operates as if the user had clicked the row?

Thanks,

-Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the grid does not have focus, so keyboard commands are not routed to it when the grid is initially displayed. You can work around this by explicitly calling [`focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) after setting your initial selection:

```
jQuery("#myGrid").setSelection(myID).focus();
```